# How to Print Columns that Splitted into Multiple Pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that have `5 columns`. 
I would like to separate it into `2 pages`.

There are `Page A` and `Page B`

`Page A` will goes like this :

```
|| No  || Col 1  || Col 2 || Col 3 || 
------------------------------------- 
||  1  ||        ||       ||       ||
||  2  ||        ||       ||       ||
```

While `Page B` will goes like this :

```
|| No || Col 4 || Col 5 ||
--------------------------
|| 1  ||       ||       ||
|| 2  ||       ||       ||
```

So everytime it prints, I would like the pages go `AB`, `AB`, `AB`.
I have tried to make two reports.

First Report contains `Page A`, and Second Report contains `Page B`. 
I put Subreport in First Report which linked to second report.

But, when I print, the printed pages goes like `AAAABBBB`

How can I set the printed pages become `AB`, `AB`, `AB` ?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Do you have source code/model? How did you model the databean? 
I am putting sample model below for reference.

```
public class DataBean {
       private String name;
       private String school;
       private List<SubReportBean> subReportBeanList;
//getters and setters

}


public class SubReportBean {

       private String address;
       private String city;
       //getter and setter
}

public class DataBeanList {
       public ArrayList<DataBean> getDataBeanList() {

          // Create sub report data
          SubReportBean subBean1 = new SubReportBean();
          //set subbean1
          SubReportBean subBean2 = new SubReportBean();
         //set subbean2
          SubReportBean subBean3 = new SubReportBean();
          //set subbean3

          ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<DataBean>();

          // Create master report data
          dataBeanList.add(generate("John", "xyz school",
             Arrays.asList(subBean1)));
          dataBeanList.add(generate("somename", "nice school",
             Arrays.asList(subBean2)));
          dataBeanList.add(generate("somename1", "cA school",
             Arrays.asList(subBean1)));


          return dataBeanList;
       }


       private DataBean generate(String name, String school,
          List<SubReportBean> subBean) {
          DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();

          dataBean.setName(name);
          dataBean.setSchool(school);
          dataBean.setSubReportBeanList(subBean);

          return dataBean;
       }
    }
```

Comment: How does your result look like? How should one use it? What if it is SQL based?

Comment: It looks something like:

Comment: It looks something like AB and then AB and so on
Name   School    
 John   xyz             Address    city
                                street1   NY




Name           School    
somename  niceschool     Address    city
                                          street2     JA


Name              School    
somename2  niceschool2     Address    city
                                              street22     JAA